# Access Report - Can't add a sum for a calculated currency column

Tags: report, ms-access-2007, calculated-columns, summary

I've generated a simple access report that is used for purchasing.

Basically, there are two tables, one for purchase orders, and one for the items on the purchase orders.

For the items on an order, I store the item details, quantity ordered, quantity delivered, and price per unit. (plus a few other fields which aren't relevant in the context of this question).

I'm generating a report to list all outstanding items still on order, and the report has a calculated field showing the outstanding quantity * cost per item. This works perfectly fine.

What I'm struggling with, is showing a sum of this calculated field (i.e. a total cost of all outstanding items), but when I try to add a total to the column, it only gives me the option of adding an item count for the column. The column is a 'Currency' field.

What might I be doing wrong, or am I expecting too much from access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved. I created the only option that the GUI would allow (item count), then modified the query from:

`=Count(*)`

to

`=Sum([Quantity]*[Cost])`

Works perfectly.